# facebook integration not working in iOS 11.0

Tags: facebook, ios11, xcode8

I am facing issue regarding login issue using facebook in ios 11.0, It doesn't work like ios 10.

not even fetch data i am not able to specify the issue because there isn't any error code.
please help if you faced this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Native code or Facebook SDK?

If you are using the native Account Kit code then you have to remove native code and use Facebook Latest SDK. this will work.

Apple has removed All Social login functionality from setting in iOS 11.